# Convert Existing Body Fields To CCK Text Fields

Tags: 6, entities

Hello i have a Content Type that has been using a body field. Now i was wanting to use a CCK text field instead. Is there a way i can convert existing node body fields for this content type to my new cck field?

Thanks

(drupal 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options spring to mind:

1. [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Safest if the amount of nodes to convert is manageable. You'll probably need to use custom PHP to make the conversion happen though, as the ready-made functionality won't cut your demands.
2. Custom script where you load each node to be converted, modify the structure and run `node_save()`.
3. SQL query, either pure SQL or by custom Drupal (Drush) script. First create your content type, then see the database structure. Then select the body text from the table `node_revisions` and insert it into your field value column for each node.

Comment: thanks kekkis. I use VBO but i wont be able to make the custom PHP so as you can guess that makes 2 not an option either for me. Ive messed about with the db before so maybe 3 would work. I have my content type 'vids' when i look in node_revisons table there doesnt seem to be a way to sort by content type. errrr

Comment: You have to join the `node` table to get the content type information: `INNER JOIN node n ON nr.vid = n.vid` where `nr` is the alias for `node_revisions`.